# How do I transfer a Windows XP/Vista/7 partition into Xen?

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-xp, xen, windows-vista

Good morning Server Fault,

I have several hard disks with installations of Windows XP, Vista, and 7. I do not want to (or rather can no longer) reinstall these Windows installations so I want to encapsulate the installations into an archive or archive parts for transfer into a Xen domU.

For starters, what format can I put this archive into, ISO? I know Windows allows entire hard drive backups in VHD format, but it's a Microsoft format that I doubt has any compatibility with Linux. Second, how do I transfer that file into Xen once I have it?

Thank you to anyone who read my question.

Comment: Are these installation on physical machines right now, or are they on partitions on disks that are attached to the Xen server?

Comment: Installations on physical machines. I have to repartition my Xen server to account for the space that will be used by these Windows partitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xen uses either `.img` files to store data, or better LVM volumes.

You might have a look at [XenServer converter](http://www.citrix.com/downloads/xenserver/tools/conversion.html).

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for. I wish I could upvote your answer as well, but I don't have enough reputation.